# Receiving messages meant for a very similar email address

Tags: gmail

I'm getting emails for a different email ID which is similar to mine but without a dot . I'm flooded with the emails meant for someone else. I'm not able to resolve it, can anyone help , or connect me with someone who works in Google and help resolve this issue. Can't believe Google could do such a blunder.

Comment: Probably duplicate: [Received an email intended for another person](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10940/354)

Comment: Also this: [Why do I receive emails sent to address similar to mine but with dots?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42131/354)

Comment: Not to mention this: [Why does Google not consider dot in usernames of Gmail addresses?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14668/354)

Answer (score 2):

Gmail ignores dots in email addresses. The following are all equivalent:

- john.doe@gmail.com
- johndoe@gmail.com
- jo.hn.do.e@gmail.com

So what seems to have happened is that someone inadvertently or with malice used your email address to sign up for something. You should contact the sending entity to get them to stop sending you messages.

Answer (score 2):

From [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en)**:

> If the sender added or removed dots from your email address, the message will still go to your inbox. Your email address is unique; people can't set up an identical account even with a different number or placement of dots.
>
> For example, messages sent to these addresses will go to the same Gmail account:
>
> - johnsmith@gmail.com
> - jo.hn.smith@gmail.com
> - john.smith@gmail.com
>
> If you still think the message was meant for someone else, contact the sender to let them know they mistyped the email address.
>
> **Note:** If you use Gmail through work, school, or other organization (like yourdomain.com or yourschool.edu), adding dots to your username changes your email address. To change the dots in your username, contact your admin.

<sup>**For more information follow the link.</sup>